# Krull dimension and elimination theory over the integers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, krull-dimension

Let $K:=\mathbb{C}$, and let $R:=K[x_1,\dots , x_n]$.

Then, a system of polynomial equations $p_1=0, p_2=0, \dots , p_r = 0$, where the $p_i$ are polynomials in the $x_j$, has finitely many solutions $\Leftrightarrow$ the Krull dimension of $R/I$ is equal to $0$, where $I:=\langle p_1, p_2, \dots , p_r \rangle$.

My question is:

Is this also true, if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

If not, is there a criterion which says sth. like

There are finitely many solutions in the $K=\mathbb{Z}$ case $\Leftrightarrow \dots$  ?

Thank you.

Comment: Ehh, this is basically what most of algebraic number theory is about. There are many varieties that are conjectured to have finitely many rational or integral points, but in most cases we can't prove anything. Faltings got the Fields medal for proving that curves of genus $\geq 2$ have finitely many rational points.

Comment: $n=2$, $r=1$, $p_1=x_2^2+1$ is a trivial counterexample.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in a comment and no more satisfactory answer is likely.

Comment: I agree and I also vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a comment, but my reputation is low, so I have to post this.

I assume that you want the solutions of $p_1=\dots=p_r=0$ to be in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then the answer is no. Take, for example, $r=1$, $n\geq 2$ and $p_1$ to be any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ that has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (say $p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1^2+1$).

If the above seems pathological (as $p_1=\dots=p_r=0$ has 0 solutions), try to experiment further with similar choices. In particular, you might want to consider a polynomial on $n$ variables that has only finitely many solutions and see what happens in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you happen to know, if there is a criterion which says sth. like

There are finitely many solutions in the $K=\mathbb{Z}$ case $\Leftrightarrow \dots$  ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. But I think that you shouldn't expect a "nice" criterion.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Do you know a sufficient criterion in the $K=\mathbb{Z}$ case which guarantees that there are only finitely many solutions, if the criterion is fulfilled?

Comment: Of course one sufficient criterion is that $R \otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Q$ has Krull dimension $0$, for then there are only finitely many rational solutions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If we know that there are only finitely many solutions, is there an algorithm to find all of them?

Comment: There is [provably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) no algorithm that determines whether a system of polynomials over $\mathbf Z$ has a solution (over $\mathbf Z$), so in particular no algorithm to find all solutions. However, in the baby case of my comment you may be able to do it (find the components of $R\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q$, determine which ones have length $1$ over $\mathbf Q$, and then determine which of these solutions have no denominators). Beyond that, already for smooth curves it is a very hard problem that seems out of reach with current technology.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Last question: If the Krull dimension of $R$ in the $K=\mathbb{Z}$ case is zero, does this imply that the Krull dimension of $R$ in the $K=\mathbb{Q}$ case is zero (via Groebner bases)? Sorry for these trivial questions...I am not familiar with this area of mathematics.

Comment: The ring $R_{\mathbf Q} = R \otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Q$ is a localisation of $R$, so $\dim R_{\mathbf Q} \leq \dim R$. But in fact it is true that $\dim R_{\mathbf Q} \leq \dim R-1$, since $\dim \mathbf Z = 1$ and components of $R$ that do not dominate $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z$ disappear in $R_{\mathbf Q}$. In particular my comment applies when $\dim R \leq 1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.